# Run pytest test suite against multiple database versions

Tags: python, pytest

I build an application that uses a database in the backend. For integration tests, I start the database in Docker and run a test suite with pytest.

I use a session scoped fixture with `autouse=True` to start the Docker container:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
    def run_database():                     
        # setup code skipped ...

        # start container with docker-py
        container.start()

        # yield container to run tests
        yield container

        # stop container afterwards
        container.stop()
```

I pass the database connection to the test functions with another session scoped fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def connection():
    return Connection(...)
```

Now I can run a test function:

```
def test_something(connection):
    result = connection.run(...)
    assert result == 'abc'
```

However, I would like to run my test functions against multiple different versions of the database.

I could run multiple Docker containers in the `run_database()` fixture. How can I parametrize my test functions so that they run for two different `connection()` fixtures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a function that yields connections and pass it with `@pytest.mark.parametrize`. If you change the the scope of `run_database()` to `class` it will run for every test

```
def data_provider():
    connections = [Connection(1), Connection(2), Connection(3)]
    for connection in connections:
        yield connection


@pytest.fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)
def run_database():
    container.start()
    yield container
    container.stop()


@pytest.mark.parametrize('connection', data_provider())
@pytest.mark.testing
def test_something(connection):
    result = connection.run()
    assert result == 'abc'
```

If you add `@pytest.mark.parametrize('connection', data_provider())` to `run_database()` the connection will be passed to there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that works! However, I did not figure out how to import the `data_provider()` function in other test modules. I found a different solution and will post another answer for reference.

Comment: @MartinPreusse Do you mean you have several `test_` in the file? or several `.py` files with a test in each?

Comment: I have several `.py` files in several folders (which all contain several `test_` functions). The foldes for test files are not supposed to be Python packages, so I did not figure out how to import.

Comment: @MartinPreusse you can put `data_provider()` in a different file, even `conftest.py`, and import it from there.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Guy works!

I found another solution for the problem. It is possible to parametrize a fixture. Every test function that uses the fixture will run multiple times: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures

Thus, I parametrized the `connection()` function:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', params=['url_1', 'url_2'])
def connection(request):
    yield Connection(url=request.param)
```

Now every test function that uses the `connection` fixture runs twice. The advantage is that you do not have to change/adapt/mark the existing test functions.